# Get element from mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `console.log('errors: ' + password.get('errors'));` to see what is returned from `password.get('errors'));` and in the console this is returned:

```
List [ Map { "id": "validation.password.tooLong", "defaultMessage": "La password deve avere massimo {max} caratteri", "values": Map { "max": 16 } } ]
```

I want to access the element `"validation.password.tooLong"` from this mapped array, I am unsure how exactly to do this. I am not 100% sure this is a mapped array, I am assuming it is though because of the `[Map...` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using immutable.js, thus to get the desired data you need to access this property via methods of these classes:

```
const errors = password.get('errors');
const errorId = errors.get(0).get('id');
```

In other answers, you got an `undefined` because List is an instance of class List, that haven't property `0`, but have a method `get` that returns a value from an array, that stored in the closure. It's a special solution to prevent mutating and ensure immutability (if you want to update value, you should use `set(0, value)` instead of `myList[0] = value`, so there is no access via `[0]`). The same thing with the Map (Map is an immutable object, that stores `key: value`).

You can learn more about it here: [Immutable.js docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/) (but I'm not sure you have exactly immutable.js, there are many similar libraries, so take a look what do you use exactly).

Comment: I am using immutable yes, but you cannot retrieve it in this way. `Cannot read get of undefined`

Comment: hm... It should be something like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b96p2qs9/). So `password.get('errors').get(0)` returns `undefined`? If yes — It looks like it's a string, instead of ImmutableJS objects. So there is two ways to work with it:

Comment: 1. Find a place where it converts into string (`.toString()` method) and remove it. And check out this isn't break something :)

Comment: 2. Parse it somehow or just use regexp (dirty hack). But better to find place where it is converting into string and refactor it.

Comment: There are explanation and both solutions: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b96p2qs9/1/)

Comment: I eventually found this solution did work, it was a simple syntax error on my part. @Kirill Shumilov JS converts .toString() as and where it can on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code:

```
var response = password.get('errors');
var result   = response[0]['id'];
```

Comment: what is 'response' contain? can you show me more info about your situation?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from map you need to use `get()` function like

```
var res = password.get('errors');
var ans   = res[0].get('id');
```